# Norm in $ \ell_{\infty} /c_0 $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Show that norm in $ \ell_{\infty} /c_0 $ is $||\overline{x} ||= \text{lim sup}|x_i|$ for each $x=(x_i)_i \in \ell_{\infty} $.

I'm doing $$||x_n+c_0||= \text{inf}_{y_n \in c_0}||(x_n)+(y_n)||_{\infty}= \text{inf}_{y_n \in c_0 } \text{sup}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|(x_n)+(y_n)|$$

I do not know what to do now. I thought to fix $y_n$ and use $y_n \to 0$, but I can not get anywhere.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805495/the-quotient-norm-on-ell-infty-mathbbn-c-0-mathbbn-is-given-by