# Norm on a subspace of $\ell^{\infty}$ is the limsup

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I am struggling to prove the following equality for all $a = \{a_n\}_n \in \ell^{\infty}$:

$\|a + c_0\|_{\frac{\ell^{\infty}}{c_0}} := \inf_{b \in c_0}\|a + b\|_{\infty} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|$.

To show this, I am trying to show that the LHS is both $\geq$ and $\leq$ the RHS of the equation. For the latter, I have

$\inf_{b \in c_0}\|a + b\|_{\infty} \leq \inf_{b \in c_0}(\|a\|_{\infty} + \|b\|_{\infty}) = \|a\|_{\infty}$ since $b = \{0, 0, ...\} \in \ell^{\infty}$, but I'm not sure where to go from there, since I don't think this last term is less than $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|$.

For the reverse inequality, I let $\epsilon > 0$ and want to show that $\sup_n |a_n| < \|a + c_0\|_{\frac{\ell^{\infty}}{c_0}} + \epsilon$. I know that for $a \in \ell^{\infty}$ and $b \in c_0$, we have $\limsup_{n \to \infty}|a_n + b_n| = \limsup_{n \to \infty}|a_n|$, but still unsure how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remember that sequences with finitely many non-zero terms belong to $c_0$. Which of these sequences could be useful to you?

Comment: Linking this post, which answers your question, but feel free to work on your own proof before looking at it if you want: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1805495/1104384